# can't get touch event in my class that implements OnTouchListener

Tags: android, touch

In Android i want to show some image and info on camera view. so i create a class with CameraPreview name to show camera on background and create a class with CanvasGenerator name to draw image and write information on camera view. every thinks work fine but i can't get touch event in my class! I want to get touch event when user touch the screen and after that close this activity

my code:

```
public class AugmentedEye implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

    private CanvasGenerator augment;


    public AugmentedEye(Context cxt, Activity acy){
        context = cxt;
        activity = acy;
    }

    public void show(){
        CameraPreview eye = new CameraPreview(context);
        augment = new CanvasGenerator(context);

        activity.setContentView(eye);
        activity.addContentView(augment,
                new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    }

    private void close(){
        augment.getValues();

        augment.off();
        activity.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        Log.d("trace", "touch happend"); // <---but it never comes here
        return false;
    }
}
```

what i have to do to get touch event?

Comment: Where you are associating this listener to a View ?

Comment: `activity.getCurrentFocus().setOnTouchListener(this);` when i write this in my construction my app crash! how i have to associate it?

Comment: Associate this to the view instead

Answer (score 1):

Because OnTouchListener interface is associated to View class. Here you are implementing it to you custom class. Always read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), as it says

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a touch event
>   is dispatched to this **view**.

Actually, onTouch event can only be occure to object those are touchable or occupy some space on UI or screen. As your class ArgumentEye is not a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). So on touch event can't be invoked on it.

As [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) is interface, it will not throw any compile or runtime execution if you implement it on non-view classes.

Comment: can you explain you answer more with a sample code?

Comment: It doesn't need example code. See the updated answer for details.